# BlockingQueue Implemetation using ReentrantLock

Tags: java, locks, blockingqueue, reentrantlock

I was writing my own implementation of BlockingQueue for practice. I am trying to avoid using the synchronized keyword for the methods. I would instead like to use ReentrantLock.

What is the best way to write this implementation?  I am not a Java ninja and would greatly appreciate if someone could pinpoint the errors in my code here and suggest better ways of implementing it.

```
public class MyBlockingQueue<T> {

private Queue<T> queue;
private AtomicInteger limit = new AtomicInteger(10);
private Lock put_lock = new ReentrantLock();
private Lock take_lock = new ReentrantLock();
private Condition put_condition = put_lock.newCondition();
private Condition take_condition = take_lock.newCondition();

public MyBlockingQueue(AtomicInteger limit){
    queue = new LinkedList<T>();
    this.limit = limit;
}

public boolean put(T item) throws InterruptedException{
    put_lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        while(queue.size() == limit.get()) {
            put_condition.await();
        }
        put_condition.signal();
        queue.add(item);
    } finally{
        put_lock.unlock();
    }

    return true;
}

public T take() throws InterruptedException{
    take_lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        while (queue.size() == 0) {
            take_condition.await();
        }
        take_condition.signal();
        return queue.poll();
    } finally {
        take_lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think the best way is reading jdk source. do you code really work ? i see many newCondition() and then await. the ptr of condition is not saved, thus, no way to awake them.

Comment: I see your point. Sure I need to save the condition first and then call await() and signal() on it.

Comment: you should first check whether code works correctly according to the promise. Check all concurrent flows. And then if you find it is not performing you can change the code.

Comment: You question, as it stands, is more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `put` and `take` use different locks and condition. As a result, they cannot interact. Meanawile, they should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare your logic with open jdk implementation of Blocking queue.

[ArrayBlockingQueue](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java#ArrayBlockingQueue)

Btw..ArrayBlockingQueue also uses **ReentrantLock**

Comment: Yeah I had a look the implementation of LinkedBlockingQueue in jdk and wrote above code.

Comment: @NPE thanks for the suggestion. I asked my question at codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample implementation of a Blocking Queue using producer-consumer problem analogy.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

public class MyBlockingQueue {
    Queue<Integer> myBlockingQueue = new LinkedList<>();
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition added = lock.newCondition();
    Condition removed = lock.newCondition();
    private static final int INITIAL_COUNT = 0;
    private static final int MAX_COUNT = 5;
    int count = INITIAL_COUNT;
    public int produce(int num) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
           while (count == MAX_COUNT) {
               System.out.println("produce: await adding, count is max");
               added.await();
           }
           addData(num);
           added.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private void addData(int num) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("added data ! " + myBlockingQueue.offer(num));
        count += 1;
    }

    private void removeData() {
        System.out.println("removed data ! " + myBlockingQueue.poll());
        count -= 1;
    }

    public int consume() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (count == 0) {
                System.out.println("consume: await removing, count is 0");
                removed.await();
            }
            removeData();
            removed.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final MyBlockingQueue instance = new MyBlockingQueue();
        List<Callable<Integer>> callableList = new ArrayList<>();
        int n = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                callableList.add(() -> instance.produce(new Random().nextInt(n * n)));
            } else {
                callableList.add(() -> instance.consume());
            }
        }
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        List<Future<Integer>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(callableList);
        System.out.println(instance.count);
        System.out.println(instance.myBlockingQueue);
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```